# Does the system of equations a + b, a * b provide a one-to-one correspondence between ordered and unordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's write ordered sets as $[a,b,c,...]$ and $\{a,b,c,...\}$ for unordered sets.

Now let $f(a,b)=[a+b,a b]$. Note $f(a,b)=f(b,a).$

Consider $g([x,y])=\{a,b\}$ where $a+b=x,a b=y$.

Mathematica's Solve function came up with $\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4 y}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{x^2-4 y}+x\right)\right\}$ as the value of $\{a,b\}$ given $[x,y]$, and in my testing, it worked for everything I threw at it. (On a philosophical note it is interesting that just from the definitions provided there's no implied order for $a$ and $b$ given $[x,y]$.)

Is this a correct one-to-one correspondence from ordered sets of two elements to unordered sets of two elements in the domain of imaginary numbers? If so, does it have a name? I'd like to find out more about it.

As an aside, the one element and three element cases seem to work also. Mathematica spent a long time trying to find equations for my guess at the four element case $a+b+c+d,a b+a c+a d+b c+b d+c d,a b c+a b d+a c d+b c d,a b c d$, but eventually I aborted it. I suspect if there is a solution, it might generalize to $n$ elements.

Also, I think it works with ordered lists and unordered lists.

Many thanks!

**Edit: as DanielWainfleet points out in the comments "if $x^2=4y$ then $g([x,y])=\{x/2\}$ which has only one element. So the above can't go from ordered sets of two elements to unordered sets of two elements.**

**So I'd like to revise the question to the highly related case of including sets of one OR two elements (unordered sets stay at two elements).**

Comment: What does $g([x,y])=\{a,b\}$ mean here? The way I would usually interpret it doesn't seem to be what you mean.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: It means that $g$ is a function from an unordered set $[x,y]$ to a set ${a,b}$. Maybe $g:[x,y]\mapsto\{a,b\}$ is more correct.

As for symmetric polynomials, they look highly related, but I'm not seeing this particular application.

Comment: (Side note: the above should read "It's supposed to mean...". I didn't mean to imply that was a reasonable way of writing that.)

Comment: If $x^2=4y$ then $g([x,y]) =\{x/2\}$ has only $1$ member.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I updated the question to allow for sets of only one element.

Comment: "Does it have a name?" -- Yes, it's called the quadratic formula along with Vieta's theorem. Because effectively, to find $a$

Comment: Wow. The system of equations on wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas ) is exactly what I was considering. I still don't see this particular interpretation/use of those equations. But thanks, this gets me a ton closer!

Comment: @zipirovich Having looked at Vieta's formulas on Wikipedia, it seems clear to me that they imply that there is a one-to-one correspondence available between ordered sets of length n and unordered sets of length 1 to n.

I think I could accept that as an answer with a little more detail if you want to post that.

Comment: @zipirovich: Since you've essentially answered this question in the comments, I'd like to get it an Answer™ so that we can remove it from the Unanswered queue. Would you mind writing that up?

Comment: @aleph_two: Thank you for your suggestion! I've typed it up as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Does it have a name?` — Yes, it's called the quadratic formula along with [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) (often also referred to as Vieta's theorem).

That's because effectively, to find $a$ and $b$, you need to solve the equation $t^2-xt+y=0$. By Vieta's formulas, the coefficients $x$ and $y$ and the roots $a$ and $b$ of this quadratic equation are related precisely in the way you defined $x$ and $y$, i.e. $x=a+b$ and $y=ab$. And the proof of this relation is fairly simple too: the quadratic equation with the roots $a$ and $b$ and the leading coefficient $1$ has to be
$$(t-a)(t-b)=0 \iff t^2-at-bt+ab=0 \iff t^2-\underbrace{(a+b)}_{x}t+\underbrace{ab}_{y}=0.$$

What you observed with three and more numbers is the same thing extended to polynomial equations of higher degree: [symmetric polynomials in the roots of a polynomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Relation_with_the_roots_of_a_monic_univariate_polynomial) are the coefficients of that equation.